# Base2 to Base5 conversion without Base10

Tags: c#, binary, radix

I'm searching for multiple hours about a conversion of base2 to base5, but I cannot find any answer or algorythm without stepping by base10.

I know exactly how to convert from decimal to quinary, but is any chance to skip it?

1010 in base2 = 10 in base10;

1010 in base2 = 20 in base5;

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried repeatedly dividing the base 10₂ value by 101₂ and using the quotient and remainder to assemble the base 101₂ value? Perhaps a better question is how are the values represented, e.g. are they strings? It's a bit hard to help without knowing that little detail. Aside: Modern processors tend to perform binary operations on integer values. Displaying the values in base ten doesn't matter to the underlying representation and operations.

Comment: Values which I get from textBoxes are strings if it may help you.

Comment: That provides a couple of obvious choices: (0) write (or find) code to parse a string in a given base to a common integer type, e.g. `int64`, and then convert the integer back to a string in a different base or (1) write (or find) code to perform arithmetic in various bases on values stored in strings. Or, if runtime isn't a concern, just count down the binary value to zero while counting up the quinary value from zero. Aside: Every base is 10 in itself.